# Created Icons looks thicker without background - how can I keep it as slick as before?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I have the following icon which sits on top of a couple of layers which one of them is a background for it.

[image]

I want to extract the icon just the way it looks here for dynamic usage in some design templates.
So to isolate the icon I make only it visible, without any background etc.

[image]

As you can see now it became way thicker and exporting it now makes it look not as expected when resused.

For me it is somewhat confusing. The layer of the icon is in "Normal" mode and so is its shadow and all the background layers below it. I can't see the reason why the result looks so weird when removing all background assets.
I'd love to extract it just the way I see it in the first screenshot but with transparency obviously.

Comment: @Wolff well be sure it's not the zoom level causing this. It looks like that as soon as I hide the background layers below

Comment: I just deleted my comment. Opened the two images in Photoshop and see what you mean. The checkered background might confuse you. How does it look with a plain white background?

Comment: The shapes are very simple and could easily be recreated from scratch in a few minutes - probably better to use a vector image editor though. Inkscape is free.

Comment: @BillyKerr Well the image is coming from Inkscape originally. I know some workaround to achieve would you suggest. Still I want to figure out what the source of the mentioned issue is

Comment: If it's from Inkscape, you can import an SVG into GIMP.

Comment: Your problem may be caused by the method of extraction.  If you import the SVG directly to its own layer, you will avoid having to extract anything.

Comment: Well I imported the SVG to a layer and applied the shadow from gimp

Comment: you can use curves in gimp to take away some alpha values from the border

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody. But as I stated I know the workaround for that. My questions is merely about WHY the mentioned problem is happing at all

Comment: @ShantanuAryan the curve tip works ! Please state as an answer!

Comment: @xetra11 done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using GIMP 2.10

- step 1: make whites whiter[image: color curves]
- step 2: use color > color to alpha[image: color to alpha]
- step 3: adjust alpha curve to remove fuzziness from borders[image: color curves]